# undefined method bytesize on Heroku

Tags: ruby, curl, heroku, icalendar

I have a heroku app that works fine on my PC, but when it runs on Heroku it complains

## Internal Server Error

undefined method `bytesize' for #<Icalendar::Calendar:0x00000000fe2c98>

---

WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2012-04-20) at
     blooming-shore-6714.herokuapp.com:80

I send the data using the command
curl -v -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data-binary @invite.ics http://blooming-shore-6714.herokuapp.com/ics2event

The file, @invite.ics, could be any ics file you have lying around.

The error is coming (I think) when I attempt to use icalendar's parse() on a stringio instance instead of a file instance.  As I read the documentation, an instance of StringIO should be compatible with files.

For reference, here's my web.rb file.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'icalendar'

get '/' do
  "new version"
end

get '/test' do
  "You've found me!"
end

post '/ics2event' do
  request.body.string

  invite = StringIO.new(request.body.string)

  cals = Icalendar.parse(invite)

  for each in cals do
    for eachEvent in each.events do
      eachEvent.summary
      eachEvent.description
      eachEvent.location
      eachEvent.status
      eachEvent.dtstart
      eachEvent.dtend
      eachEvent.organizer
      for eachAttendee in eachEvent.attendees do
        eachAttendee.to
      end
    end
  end

end
```

So the question is, how do I make it go away?

Comment: I forgot to mention.  When I try the parsing locally using the ruby command--everything works.  It only fails when I try to run it as a web service.